# JSF not reading resources folder

Tags: jsf

I am having a problem getting JSF to read my resources folder that contains my stylesheets.  My css library folder is located at /webroot/resources/css/style.css

I have used the outputstylesheet tag before with no problems but I don't know what I am missing here.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"/>
    <title>Home</title>  
</h:head>
```

Any ideas?

---

**Update**: here's a portion of my `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Can you open http://localhost:8080/contextpath/resources/css/style.css individually? (where the `/contextpath` part is obviously your context path). What exactly does it return? Do you have some access-restriction filters mapped on an overly generic URL pattern which also matches the JSF resources?

Comment: Hi, yes I can access the stylesheet that way, the stylesheet gets displayed in the browser.  As for the last question, I'm not sure what you mean but I think you are referring to information in my web.xml file.  I will post it in an answer post, not enough room here in the comment area...

Comment: No, please don't post question updates as answers, just edit them into the question :) As to the problem, what URL is generated by JSF when you rightclick the HTML result in browser and do *View Source*? Can you open it individually? What do you get?

Comment: `
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>`

Comment: I don't know how to format correctly in comments, sorry.  I can access the stylesheet as well by using the URL in the source.  JSF renders  href="/JSF/faces/javax.faces.resource/style.css?ln=css" as my stylesheets location.  It opens correctly.  I am quite baffled by this.  I am using Netbeans but I seriously doubt that has anything to do with it!

Comment: Just click "edit" link below the question to edit your question :) I'll do it for you. How about the generated URL? Or didn't JSF generate any HTML at all and are you just seeing the raw JSF source code?

Comment: ps. JSF rendered the HTML correctly.

Comment: @BalusC I figured out that for some reason my css file isn't being updated when I build my project.  Any changes I make aren't being reflected in the css displayed when I use the link to the css in the html source.  The css in the source is the original blank stylesheet that was created when I first added the stylesheet to the project.  Any idea how to update it to the current one?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you elaborate how you're building the project.

Comment: With the default ant script provided by Netbeans.  I figured out that it seems to be a cache issue with Firefox.  Everytime I rebuild and deploy the app the old stylesheet is applied.  When I hit refresh the current style pops up.  I'm sure there is a workaround for it somehow.  It's not a JSF problem as I first thought anyway!  Thanks for the help.